# Как узнать точную дату на php?

Tags: php, дата

Вывожу дату с помощью функции `date()` и пробовал в БД указывать `timestamp`, но в ходе эксперемента выявил что если изменить дату в календаре на ПК то и эти же функции будут думать что сегодня этот день на который я поменял. Как узнать точную дату не зависящую от ПК календаря?

Comment: вы на сервере будете время менять? у вас скрипт работает локально, поэтому и смена времени влияет. у клиентов сайта будет отображаться естественно серверное время, а не то что у них на компе. надеюсь, это вам понятно и так. В противном случае, дату можете запросить у какого нибудь сервиса в сети.

Answer (score 4):

Дата, выводимая через date(), всегда будет зависеть от того сервера, на котором обрабатывается код. Сейчас этим сервером является ваш комп.
Когда ваш сайт переедет на нормальный хостинг, то там будет другой сервер, на котором будет установлена точная дата. Пользователи на нее повлиять не смогут.